# How to boost a field with maintaining its old value

Tags: solr, solr-boost

I am using solr 4.10.3. I have indexed some data using Nutch. I have to boost a field of a document in solr such that its old data is maintained just attributed boost is changed.

What is the solution ?

Comment: you can define the boost for the fields in your search handler in solrconfig file. Boost works during the query time not during index time. Explain in detail, what exactly are you looking for with example

Comment: Basically, I want to show results for a particular website at top in solr search. How can can do it or what configuration I should change for it?

Comment: Please provide your field name, sample input and select handler part from your sourconfig file. As far as I understood you just needs to add filed_name^10 in qf of your select handler defaults.